# "Don't show a title on my profile" does nothing

Tags: bug, profile-page

In [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker?tab=profile) it says:

[image]

I'd rather not have that title, since it's just a repeat of what's already in the profile description, so I try to edit it:

[image]

But that doesn't seem to do anything; it blanks the input field, but if it's blank, the current position is shown by default it seems.

Comment: If I look at your profile, your title is gone

Comment: @Ferrybig For me, it's only gone at his Meta profile, but it's still there on the main site.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, did you set your profile on main, or on meta?:) I never considered them to be separate, but why not?

Comment: @AndrasDeak On the main site.

Comment: FWIW: If I use your [link provided](http://stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker?tab=profile) I see it on both sites, but if I just [go to your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker) it's only visible on the main site, not meta

Comment: I see it on SO and not MSO. No shenanigans. Doesn't matter what link I use. Apply to both sites.